# Qt program does not detect libraries

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, libraries

I built a Qt application and included the necessary libraries needed in the build directory. When I try to run the application from a different computer, it doesn't work.

This is the `ldd` output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff8c7fe000)
libQt5Widgets.so.5 => not found
libQt5Gui.so.5 => not found
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f5cb4143000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f5cb3f2d000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5cb3b6c000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5cb3870000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5cb4456000)
```

The files not found are in the same directory as the binary. How do I make them detectable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux current binary directiry is not the place where the loader looks for shared libraries. See this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/279068/cant-find-so-in-the-same-directory-as-the-executable

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following to your .pro file to force the dynamic linker to look in the same directory as your Qt application at runtime in Linux :

```
unix:{
    # suppress the default RPATH if you wish
    QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH=
    # add your own with quoting gyrations to make sure $ORIGIN gets to the command line unexpanded
    QMAKE_LFLAGS += "-Wl,-rpath,\'\$$ORIGIN\'"
}
```